# How to find a string in a list of case class

Tags: scala, list

I have a case class `Color`

```
scala> case class Color(code: String, qty: String, shadecode: String, foo: Int)
```

I have a list of case class

```
scala> val c = List[Color](Color("100", "10", "99"), Color("200", "20", "88"), Color("300", "10", "99"))
```

How can I determine whether this string is present in the list:

```
scala> val colorString = "1001099"
```

The convention of the string will always be the same. First three characters will be `code`, next two will be `qty`, and last two will be `shadecode`

I've tried the following but it doesn't work since I am not passing any value for `foo`:

```
def doesExist(s: String, colors: Color): Boolean = {
  return colors.exists(_==Color(code= s.substring(0,3), qty = s.substring(3,4), shadecode = s.substring(5,6)))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
def findColor(s: String, colors: Seq[Color]): Option[Color] = {
   val (code, qty, shadecode) = (
     s.substring(0,3), 
     s.substring(3,5), 
     s.substring(5,7))
   colors.find(c => c.code == code && c.qty == qty && c.shadecode == shadecode)
}

val exists = findColor("1001099", colors).isDefined
```

If the list of colors is large and static (meaning you search in the same list all over again many times), you may also want to build an index instead (to get this from `O(n)` to `O(1)` --- but only if you can reuse the index a lot).

```
val indexedColors: Map[String, Color] = colors.map(c => (c.toCodeString, c)).toMap
val exists = indexColors.containsKey("1001099")
```

Comment: what is `toCodeString` here?

Comment: the function you add to your case class to go from Color to the string that would match it, i.e. `s"${code}${qty}${shadecode}"`.

Comment: Thanks I think having a Map index makes a ton of sense

Comment: For 75K entries, an external database may also make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Add a function inside your case class and use that function to check if the string is a match. Here's the simple solution:

```
case class Color(code: String, qty: String, shadecode: String, foo: Int) {
  def matchString(colorString: String): Boolean = {
    val (code, qty, shadecode) = (
      colorString.substring(0,3),
      colorString.substring(3,5),
      colorString.substring(5,7))

    this.code == code && this.qty == qty && this.shadecode == shadecode
  }
}
```

And then:

```
 val exists = YOUR_COLOR_LIST.exists(_.matchString(YOUR_STRING))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create the key early so the search is faster

```
case class Color(code: String, qty: String, shadecode: String) {
  val k = s"$code$qty$shadecode"
}
val c = List[Color](Color("100", "10", "99"), Color("200", "20", "88"), Color("300", "10", "99"))
c.filter(_.k == "1001099") // Color(100,10,99)
c.exists(_.k == "1001099") // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reframe your function using deep matching functionality of case classes:

```
def doesExist(s: String, colors: List[Color]): Boolean = {
  val (code, qty, shadecode) = (s.substring(0,3), s.substring(3,5), s.substring(5,7))
  colors.exists{
    case Color(`code`, `qty`, `shadecode`, _) => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

And also, the parameters you were providing to `substring` method for `qty` and `shadecode` were incorrect.

Comment: Does exists stop soon as it finds a match or it goes through the entire list regardless?

Comment: It stops as soon as it can.